# laravel querying data details by processing

Tags: json, laravel

I am pulling my data with this code as in the picture

What I want to do is to collect the size numbers of the ordered colors, for example, I want to get the sum of the size 34 of the black color and the overall total number of each size. and if there is more than one color, how should I go about grouping the size of these colors?

```
$co = CollectionOrder::where('cut_id', $request->cut_id)->get();

    $data = array(
        'order'=> collect($co)->map(function($value, $key) {
            return [
                'plm_id'=>$value->plm_id,
                'collection_color'=>$value->collectionColor->color_name,
                'warehouse_id'=>$value->warehouse_id,
                'receiver_id'=>$value->receiver_id,
                'unit_price'=>$value->unit_price,
                'order_date'=>$value->order_date,
                'delivery_date'=>$value->delivery_date,
                'piece'=>collect($value->orderPiece)->map(function($value, $key) {
                    return [

                        'size'=>$value->CollectionColorSizeBarcode->size,
                        'piece'=>$value->piece,
                    ];
                }),
            ];
        }),
    );
```

[image]

can i show it like this in the design;

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote, which is rather important, always try to avoid posting images of code and instead post that code directly into your question so we could try to use it and reproduce your issue.

Comment: The desired output you provided doesn't seem to be in sync with what you have described in your question.

Comment: how should i go about